# Angualar JS translate e elementos dinâmicos?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Estou usando AngularJS para criar um site multi-lingual, porém estou havendo problemas com os elementos criados de forma dinâmica.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
         'title': 'title'

    }.translations('pt', {
         'title': 'titulo'
    }

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

<div ng-app="myApp" id="myDiv">
      <span>{{ 'title' | translate }}</span>
</div>
```

Porém se eu adicionar uma nova `span` à minha div, com por exemplo:

```
$("#myDiv").append("<span>{{ 'title' | translate }}</span>");
```

O conteúdo da `span` não é traduzido com o valor de `title`.

Comment: `$()` apenas adiciona conteúdo ao DOM. Para que o conteúdo seja interpretado pelo angular você precisa passá-lo pelo `$compile`, que o adicionará ao escopo. Exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database

Comment: Então toda vez que eu for add um novo elemento devo passá-lo pelo compile?

Comment: Sim. Internamente é isso que o AngularJS faz com todos os objetos sob um `scope` específico. A solução no link que lhe passei inplementa a compilação como uma diretiva.